# How to get current language in 3ds max script

Tags: max, 3dsmax, maxscript

I find all the help files of 3ds Max Script Reference, but can't get the api about get current language.
I already try `3ds Max System Globals` and `MAXScript System Globals`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [sysInfo.getMaxLanguage()](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAXDEV/2022/ENU/?guid=GUID-CAC36F27-CB51-4C9F-B265-167F636C9A4D#system-language-and-locale-).